# Configure SQL server to force encryption programmatically

Tags: sql-server, tls-1.2

I'd like to enable the [ForceEncryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#configure-server) flag for SQL server programmatically.

I tried:

```
    Set-ItemProperty `
        -Path "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib" `
        -Name ForceEncryption `
        -Value 1;
```

But that didn't seem to reject connections when they were unencrypted (I was still getting rows returned by `SELECT session_id FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE encrypt_option != 'TRUE'`).

I'm trying to get the configuration described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-encryption-without-validation?view=sql-server-ver15), where clients connect with the `TrustServerCertificate` option set to true (and as such encryption occurs using a self signed certificate).

I'm using SQL Server 2019.  The database is running on the same host as the code that is trying to connect to the database. The script is also running on that host. It is not a named instance.  I have restarted the SQL Server instance - with no effect.

Comment: Are you sure the application uses TCP instead of shared memory or named pipes? Check net_transport column on sys.dm_exec_connections.